# This interaction flow could be improved

Tags: bug, user-interface, login, openid

I just went through the following sequence:

1. Go to superuser.com.
2. Compose a post with text and tags.
3. Scroll down to post, and realize I'm not logged in.
4. Open a fresh tab on superuser.com.
5. Click on the login tab, and maybe select OpenID, but before I can start entering data (*my OpenID is http://JonathansCorner.com handled by http://JonathanHayward.MyOpenID.com, and I believe I clicked "Remember me for three weeks" on the MyOpenID login page*), the system logs me in and presents a welcome back message at the top.
6. Go to the tab that I had composed my question in.
7. Hit "Reload" and be presented with a dire warning about leaving a page that has state.
8. Click the "Yes, I really want to reload after your warning about losing data" button.
9. Page is reloaded perfectly, with all of the state in question text and tags preserved.
10. Hit "post" button, and flow from here on is as if I had logged in first and then posted my question second.

This workflow has a couple of points of possible improvement. First, it would be nice if the main page recognized me like the login page did. Second, if it doesn't recognize me, "OpenID" would be a nice addition to the login options, possibly at the expense of more screen real estate if you use that option. Third, reload the page to get what you have composed as belonging to your account is a valid use case, and the code should be tweaked so that someone who hits reload to get login status updated does not get dire warnings implying that you will lose state. The system is good enough that you don't lose state in any way that I can tell, and maybe the code needs to distinguish a reload from a closed tab etc., unless JavaScript doesn't support such discrimination.